# How to add a WebView as a content to a tab in JavaFX?

Tags: webview, javafx, tabs

i'm looking for what is the right way to set content in a Tab and how to set the WebView with a demonsion i tried this code:

```
if (cancell.isVisible()){
       tabs.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new          ChangeListener<Number>() {
       @Override
       public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        hyst.setVisible(false);
        cancell.setVisible(false);
        final WebView wb = new WebView();
        wb.setLayoutX(-1);
        wb.setLayoutY(128);
        wb.setPrefHeight(700);
        wb.setPrefWidth(1604);
        WebEngine pp = wb.getEngine();
        t.setContent(wb);
        pp.load("http://www.google.com");
       }
     });
     }
```

please can any body help me and thank youu !!

Comment: i think your code is fine, but the only problem is `tabs` or `wb` can't change size of the stage or some parent view, so you can't see any chages. set some size for  your scene and tabs root.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your webView in a pane ?